# Google Sitebricks Session Management

Tags: java, guice, sitebricks

I explored Sitebricks [website](http://www.sitebricks.org) and related forums but could not find out if it supports session management (preserving state across multiple requests) or not. Just wondering if anyone knows the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitebricks is based on the Guice Servlet extension of Guice, which allows you to scope injected objects by session either by annotating them with [@SessionScoped](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/SessionScoped.html) or by specifying session scope when you bind in a module:

```
bind(Something.class).to(SomeImplementation.class).in(SessionScoped.class);
```